# Searching for partilcular numbers in PHP

Tags: php

I have been working on a requirement (in PHP), where I had stuck with the below.

I need to search for the numbers between 6800 to 6899. How can I search starts with the string ‘68’. So that I will get all the numbers in that range.

Now, I have an idea like:

```
if ($Model== 'Jazz6800i') return true;
if ($Model== 'Jazz6801i') return true;
......
if ($Model== 'Jazz6899i') return true;
```

Do we have any alternate in PHP instead of writing hell lot of code, to search starting with 68?

Answer (score 7):

Use regexp:

```
function isInCorrectRange($item) 
{
    return preg_match('/Jazz68[0-9][0-9]i/', $item);
}

$result = isInCorrectRange('Jazz6801i');
```

Comment: **Simple** - in one word. I think the function is not needed BTW. :)

Comment: Looks more pretty in function :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_replace`, `in_array`, `range` for this.

```
$model = str_replace(array('Jazz', 'i'), '', $model);
if(in_array($model, range(6800, 6899))) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
for ($i=0;$i<=99;$i++)
{
    If ($Model == 'Jazz68'.$i.'i')
    {   
        echo "Found ! for Jazz68".$i."i";
        break;
    }
}
```